Errorhandling Microsoft Teams Uninstallation with teamsbootstrapper (with start-process)
I am struggling with the error handling for the uninstallation of Microsoft Teams by using their teamsbootstrapper.exe.
With teamsbootstrapper's -x flag, the uninstallation will be success: "true" or success: "false"
But the function (below) won't show the correct output of teamsbootstrapper.exe:
$team = "$PSScriptRoot\teamsbootstrapper.exe"
$msix = "$PSScriptRoot\MSTeams-x64.msix"

function InstallTeams {
    param(
    )
    try {
        $r = Start-Process -FilePath `"$team`" -ArgumentList "-x"  -Wait
        $resultObj = try { $r | ConvertFrom-Json } catch { $null }
        if ($resultObj -eq $null -or $resultObj.success -eq $false) {
            throw ''
        }
        write-host 'ERROR: Teams uninstallation failed'
        return $false
    }
    catch {
        write-host 'Teams uninstallation is done'
        return $true
    }
}

InstallTeams

With PowerShell there is no output shown, while using "teamsbootstrappe.exe -x", with cmdlet you will get success: "true" or success: "false".
First question: How can I catch the output in PowerShell?
Second question: Is there a method to get an installation failed with teamsbootstrapper.exe? Everytime the uninstallation is success
Several output methods, nothing catches the "true" or "false".

As an aside: You seem to have accidentally swapped return $true and return $false and the associated Write-Host statements  in your code.

teambootstrapper -x



How can I catch the output in powershell?


Fundamentally, you cannot directly capture process output from a Start-Process call - all you can do is to redirect it to files, using -RedirectStandardOutput and RedirectStandardError.

That said, except in special circumstances, there is no need to use Start-Process to synchronously invoke a program that produces stdout (and possibly also stderr) output, i.e. a console(-subsystem) application:

Simply use direct invocation in that case, which is implicitly synchronous and connects the application process' stdout and stderr streams directly to PowerShell's output streams.

Additionally, PowerShell then implicitly reflects the process exit code in the automatic $LASTEXITCODE variable.

In fact, a nonzero $LASTEXITCODE value is usually a more reliably indicator of failure than examining the application's output (but only if that application honors this widely observed exit-code convention).






Therefore, if you want to stick with your approach of analyzing the application's stdout output, replace the Start-Process call with the following (while keeping the rest of your code):
# Use direct invocation; note the need to use &, the call operator,
# for syntactic reasons.
$r = & $team -x



Is there a method to get an installation failed with teamsbootstrapper.exe?

Consider using the most widely used PowerShell testing framework, Pester, which allows you to mock command calls, allowing you to simulate failure.

I have this. I doubt it sets an exit code. The result is output in json text.
.\teambootstrapper -x

{
  "success": true
}

Alternatively (remove-appxprovisionedpackage has no -whatif parameter!):
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -online | ? displayname -eq msteams |
  Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -allusers

Path          :
Online        : True
RestartNeeded : False

Hopefully $? is set to $false if there's an error.

That the installer's output is JSON, with the structure you're spelling out, is implied by the question itself. Targeting .\teambootstrapper isn't the same as targeting "$PSScriptRoot\teamsbootstrapper.exe", which is what the question does.
